# How to add Run Nested applications in AioHttp

Tags: aiohttp

I am trying out nested application in AIOhttp but can't get it to run.

If I want my url to be like `localhost/greet/` and `localhost/greet/abc`, I am using the following code but giving me `404 Not Found` so my routing is not correct.

I am not able to find much online resources here as well.

Below is my code:

```
app = web.Application()
greet = web.Application()

app.router.add_get('/', index)
greet.router.add_get('/{name}', handle_name, name='name')

app.add_subapp('/greet/', greet)

web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)

async def handle_name(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    txt = "Hello {}".format(name)
    return web.Response(text=txt)
```

Any guidance will be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what your problem was, but this works fine:

```py
from aiohttp import web

async def index_view(request):
    return web.Response(text='index\n')

async def subapp_view(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    txt = "Hello {}\n".format(name)
    return web.Response(text=txt)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', index_view)

greet = web.Application()
greet.router.add_get('/{name}', subapp_view)

app.add_subapp('/greet/', greet)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

and then testing with curl:

```
~ 0  25ms ➤  curl localhost:8080/
index
~ 0  33ms ➤  curl localhost:8080/greet/world
Hello world
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: One of those moments when you don't know why the code didn't work before your answer. It works perfectly now. Thank you!